# What should the tag "space-filling" be used for?

Tags: discussion, tags

We currently have 2 questions tagged [space-filling](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/space-filling). The first is a [question](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/what-is-the-difference-between-various-space-filling-curves) about *[space filling curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve)*. The second is a [question about](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1747/with-modern-fillrates-and-deferred-rendering-is-occlussion-culling-still-releva) GPU fill rates.

Without a tag wiki it is not clear which of these uses the tag should fulfill. It seems unhelpful for a tag to have two conflicting meanings.

How should we approach this?

Answer (score 4):

These seem like fairly different concepts. I think "space filling" seems like a bit of a stretch for being used in the context of fill rates. I definitely associate space filling curves with that.

The question would be more appropriately tagged with [gpu](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gpu), maybe [hardware](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardware), or even just a new [fillrate](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fillrate) tag.

Comment: Agree with the `fillrate` tag

Comment: And honestly, I doubt we need a tag for space-filling curves at all. They're not *that* common of a topic. :)